# Where can I find the latest version of java's jdk 13 for windows x86 / 32 bit

Tags: java, eclipse

I am transitioning from php to java. Eclipse is my chosen ide for development.
When I go to Oracle's website, I'm failing to locate jdk13 for windows 32 bit / x86. I've tried searching their website to no avail.
Here is the link I tried: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.
My question is:
1. Is there somewhere else I can get a download file.
2. If not, would jdk12 still have support, and would it work with the latest version of Eclipse.

Again, I'm new to this. Sorry if the answer is obvious.

Comment: Oracle is just one JDK provider. For example, I use JDKs and JREs from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) because they are free.

Comment: Oracle stopped making 32 bit java binaries after java 1.8. Java 9 and forward are only 64 bit but in this day and age why do you need a 32 bit java?

Comment: Recent versions of Eclipse are 64 bit only, and only the current version of Eclipse supports Java 13 fully.

Comment: I honestly had no idea there was more than one provider of jdk. Kind of feeling stupid, but thank you all. AdoptOpenJDKAdoptOpenJDK is downloading.

Comment: Well, there are [quite a number of (Open)JDK vendors/providers](https://twitter.com/rafaelcodes/status/1188593461064359936) these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try downloading from OpenJDK (it doesn't require you to create an account etc.) [here](https://jdk.java.net/13/) . I don't know if they support 32-bit but you can look around.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below:

- Open [this link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) in browser ;
- Click on *Accept License Agreement* (radio button) ;
- Click on `jdk-8u201-windows-i586.exe` to download Windows x86 (32 bits version of JDK).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Oracle, AdoptOpenJDK is a good source: https://adoptopenjdk.net/ With regards to ver 13, have a look here: https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk13&jvmVariant=hotspot